# Macro for while loop with deferred function call

Tags: c++, while-loop, preprocessor

I would like to construct a macro where a predefined function (here simulated by "call fcn here") is called every time when the loop ends an iteration. This is what I have so far, which actually works.

Is there shorter way, eventually with more macro magic to write such behavior?

```c
#define MYWHILE(condition) \
        while(  \
          []()->bool {  \
          static bool called = false; \
          if(called) std::cout<<"call fcn here"<<std::endl; \
          called=true; return true;}() \
          && condition)
```

This macro should than be used on several places in the code to ensure than nobody forgets to call the function when they write busy waiting loops.

A typical example would be:

```c
while(true){

 bool b = foo();
 if(b){
   break;
 }

 ros::spinOnce(); 
}
```

Where oft the call `ros::spinOnce()` is forgotten, so I simply replace the sample code with:

```c
MYWHILE(true){

  bool b = foo();
  if(b){
    break;
  }
}
```

Pure C - Code would also be fine.

Comment: do not use preprocessor macros any more, they mostly are more harmful than useful

Comment: Put this code in a function instead of a macro.

Comment: Why are you not simply using a `do {} while` loop, which does exactly the behavior you described? (Though not the behavior you have in your code. Which did you want?)

Comment: On the second and later times execution enters your loop, your implementation will call the predefined function the first time thru because the static bool will already be set to `true` from the previous time thru the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a complicated looking `while` loop, you can package up what you need into a `for` loop:

```
for (; condition; fcn())
```

The function will be called at the end of every iteration, before reevaluating the condition.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to construct a macro where a predefined function (here
>   simulated by "call fcn here") is called every time when the loop ends
>   an iteration, but NOT at the first time.

Since your provided code and your question conflict, it is not clear what behavior you want. To implement the above, I would recommend not using macros at all and simply writing your code as:

```
do {
  if(!condition)
    break;

  // More code here

} while(fcn());
```

Comment: Or the simpler `for (; condition; fcn())`

Comment: sorry for the confusing description. The function should be called after the first iteration. I mean at the beginning of the second iteration which is actually the same.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: True, I guess I was assuming his function needed to be part of the condition. A `for` loop woudn't allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just:

```
while(!foo()) {
    ros::spinOnce();
}
```

That is logically equivalent to:

```
while(true){
    bool b = foo();

    if(b){
        break;
    }
    ros::spinOnce(); 
}
```

Yet far simpler than:

```
MYWHILE(true){
    bool b = foo();

    if(b){
        break;
    }
}
```